# What is self-referential window property in client-side javascript?

Tags: javascript, client-side

I am studying a book on Javascript, "**Javascript: The Definitive Guide - *David Flanagan***". Chapter 3 of this book talks about the Global object, here, they say that

> global Window object has a **self-referential window property** that can
>   be used instead of **this** to refer to the global object.

What I understand from the above line is that window is not the object instead it is self-reference, but could someone explain me in detail how it is.. and how to create a self-referential property for a custom object.

Like in chrome console if I type in **window** i get

> Window {top: Window, location: Location, document: document, window:
>   Window, external: Object…}

How to achieve the same for custom objects. Sorry, if I understood this totally wrong please excuse me for that, I am newbie to JS.

Answer (score 3):

Self-referential means that the `Window` object has a property which references itself.

```
window.window = window
```

When you're in the `window` scope, `this === window` so you can reference properties like `window.location` using the following methods.

1. `window.location`
2. `this.location`
3. `location`
4. `window.window.location`
5. `this.window.location`
6. etc...

Answer (score 2):

You understood it wrong. It means that the `window` object has a member called `window` which is a reference to the `window` object itself. That is to say,

```
window.window === window
```

Adding some quotes to the quote might clarify it a bit:

> global Window object has a self-referential "window" property...

(i.e. global Window object has a property called "window" that is self-referential.)

Although it's very rarely useful, to create one for a custom object you just assign itself to a member element.

```
var obj = {};
obj.obj = obj;
```

Comment: One small doubt but what is the need of a self-referential property like dat... is there any specific reason to that for window object ?

Comment: It's not very useful in practice. There are several use cases mentioned at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/window